# Pandas: what is the best way to stratify a dataset by some column and save each partition?

Tags: python, pandas

What would be better than

```
grouped = df.groupby('A', sort=False)
for name, group in grouped:
    filename = name + '.csv' 
    del group['A']
    group.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

I'm just trying to improve my Python/Pandas skills.

Answer (score 0):

That solution looks good to me.
An alternative could be to use list comprehension to generate name, data frame tuples which you could then iterate over and save:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

#Create some random data
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A': [random.randint(1, 10) for x in xrange(200)], \
                   'Data' : [random.random() for x in xrange(200)]})

#Create list of tuples where first element in each tuple is the name of the group
#and the second element is a data frame containing the data relating to that group. 

segments = [(group[0], pd.DataFrame(group[1])) for group in DF.groupby('A', sort = False)]
```

You could then iterate over segements to save, or to browse them, or whatever you fancy really.... The list comprehension saves you some code lines, but I'm not sure its necessarily better than what you were doing.